# Adding UISplitviewController to nib file of universal app, object not showing

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

So I've upgraded my iphone app to a universal app and am trying to add a uisplitviewcontroller. In MainWindow-ipad.xib, when I try to drag an object to the window, uisplitviewcontroller isn't an option. Furthermore, the screen size is the iphone's dimensions, not the ipad's. How do I get this to work with the universal app?

Thanks.

[Valid XHTML http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/504/screenshot20100809at436.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/504/screenshot20100809at436.png)

Comment: It says the UIViewController is only available for the ipad?

Comment: Any help would be great. I've seen many universal apps allow the splitview, but I'm not sure how their library includes the splitview controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how to do it. You have to convert it to an iPad nib.